# Getting a problem with doWhile in Gatling while doing requests

Tags: java, gatling

I am trying to execute a doWhile but I am getting this compilation error:

> missing argument list for method doWhile in trait Loops
> Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
> You can make this conversion explicit by writing `doWhile _` or `doWhile(_,_)(_)` instead of `doWhile`.

This is my code:

```
    builder
  .doWhile("${scrollId.exists()}") {
    exec(http(s"$title")
      .post(endpoint)
      .headers(headers)
      .body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath))
      .check(jsonPath("$.scrollId").saveAs("scrollId"))
      .check(status.is(200)))
      .pause(1)
      //save value from response
      .exec(session => {
        .doIf(session("scrollId").asOption[String].isEmpty)
      val scrollId = session("scrollId").asOption[String].get
      session.set("scrollId", scrollId)
    })
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for `doWhile` is `doWhile(condition) { chain }`, eg:

```scala
builder
        .doWhile("${scrollId.exists()}") {
        exec(http(s"$title")
          .post(endpoint)
          .headers(headers)
          .body(ElFileBody(requestBodyFilePath))
          .check(jsonPath("$.scrollId").saveAs("scrollId"))
          .check(status.is(200)))
        .pause(1)
      //save value from response
          .exec(session => {
            val scrollId = session("scrollId").asOption[String].get
            session.set("scrollId", scrollId)
          })
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your are right, also, can you tell me how can I check the value of session("scrollId").asOption[String] before doing the get? Is this okay?

  I just edited the code

Comment: @i Please stick to 1 question = 1 post on StackOverFlow. Here, please create a new one.